# How to override isc-dhcpd option in child group, to hide default gateway

Tags: gateway, isc-dhcpd

Given the below configuration, how can I undo the `routers` option for the inner `group` so that certain machines don't get told what the default gateway is from the outer `group`?

```
group {
  # A bunch of options go here which should apply to all clients.
  option domain-name-servers ...
  option routers 192.168.0.1;

  # This host should be told about the default gateway.  This is just an example,
  # there are many more.
  host example1 { }

  group {
    # This group should have no default gateway supplied by the DHCP server,
    # but otherwise inherit all the options from the parent group.
    option routers 0.0.0.0;

    host example2 { }
  }

  # There are many other groups that I have omitted for simplicity.
  group { }
}
```

In my case I am using some IP cameras I bought from China, and they phone home (actually to servers located in the US) but nonetheless there is no way to disable this on the devices themselves.  I have blocked the traffic at my firewall but I would prefer that it doesn't even get that far, by telling the camera there is no default gateway available, so it doesn't know where to send packets destined for outside my network.

When I use the above config, the `0.0.0.0` option is ignored by the ISC DHCP server and it still gives out the gateway inherited from the parent group.

Is there a way to completely override the `routers` option from the parent `group { }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "option dhcp-parameter-request-list" to limit the parameters that the DHCP server can return to the client. see man page for [dhcp-options (5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-options).
In that innermost group add something like:

```
option dhcp-parameter-request-list 1,2,6,12,15,42,51,53,54,61,119;
```

Note that the routers option has a code number of 3, so we are leaving that one out of the allowed list. See [RFC-2132](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132.html) for the list of DHCP options and their codes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I came up with a less than ideal workaround, which is to set the gateway to localhost:

```
option routers 127.0.0.1;
```

It's not ideal as the host thinks it has an Internet connection that is broken, rather than no connection at all, but it's better than nothing!